# Scaling Box for Exercises

Tags: minipage, scaling, proof-package

I've been using the following code to include numbered exercises in a book I'm writing using the `amsbook` class:

```
\newcounter{exercise}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newenvironment{exercise}
    {\refstepcounter{exercise}%

    \vspace{1em}%
    \noindent%
    \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.98\hsize}%
        \noindent\textbf{Exercise~\theexercise \\ }%
    }%
    {\end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}
        \fbox{\usebox{\mybox}}\\[1em]%
    }
```

I'm pretty sure some kind soul on this platform helped me build this code, and it works fabulously except for one thing: sometimes, I want to put an exercise in the middle of a proof. E.g., I sometimes want to do this:

```
\begin{proof}
  By induction.
  \begin{exercise}
    Do the base case
  \end{exercise}
  The rest of the proof
\end{proof}
```

Ideally, when I do such a thing the exercise box would scale to fit the size of the text inside the proof environment. I've tried fiddling with alternatives to \hsize to make this happen, but none have worked. I'm suspicious that `minipage` is mucking things up, but I can't quite see how to fix it.

Comment: This may or may not provide what you want, but look up `xca` in the user guide for `amsthm` (`texdoc amsthdoc`).  Exercises using this environment can be embedded in a proof environment.

Comment: Hmm.. The exercises lI have embed in a proof environment, they just don't scale appropriately when so-embedded. ALso I *really* like having the exercises in little boxes, so it's more clear where they start and stop. I like the idea, though!

Comment: Apologies -- I missed the presence of `\fbox` in your code.  When you're packing something into an `\fbox` you need to set the text width taking into consideration the space between the text and the rules (I think it's `\fsep`, times two) and the thickness of the rules (i think this is `.4pt`, again times two).  If you want it indented, you have to add that into the calculation.  98% may not be quite small enough.  (I didn't check.)